# Run Cron every 2 minutes in 30 minutes?

Tags: cron, cronjob

I need to run a cron job every 2 minutes (`*/2`) but *only* for the first 30 minutes of every hour, with pause of 30 minutes between the runs.

For example, something like:

- From 10h00 to 10h30: run every 2 minutes
- From 10h30 to 11h00: nothing to run
- From 11h00 to 11h30: run every 2 minutes
- etc...

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: is this homework? You could wrap the command in a script to loop 15 times {call command, wait 2 minuets}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you run after the half hour instead of before? If so this should work for you...

```
30/2 * * * *
```

If not you would have to designate each of the minutes you want it to run...

```
2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30 * * * *
```

Not sure if your hourly was supposed to recur throughout the day or not but I assumed so.

Comment: Perfect. Simple way, i was thinking for something much more complicated instead of thinking a simple way... thanks

Comment: I brain farted and had an extra 0 in front... not even sure how it ended up there, lol. I corrected it though so make sure what you took from it matches.

Answer (score 1):

this should work: `0-30/2 * * * *`